# Grails Project jdbc TSQL how to create a datetime2 column

Tags: t-sql, grails, jdbc

Hi I have a Grails project and regardless what data kind for dates (`java.sql.Timestamp`, `java.util.Date`) I offer in the Domain Class it always creates a `datetime` column in the TransactSQL Database ( Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 . I need a `datetime2` Field.

Does anybody know what data type I can use that the DomainClass creates a `datetime2` Field?

I use this : postgresql-9.0-801.jdbc4.jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your mapping section:

```
dateField(sqlType: 'datetime2')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use mapping to customize database type

```
class Address {

         Date  date

         static mapping = { date type: 'datetime2' } 

}
```

Comment: Hi, if I try to do this I get a error at Compiling
`Could not determine type for: datetime2, at table: relationship, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(send_date)]`

Comment: hmmm.. have you set the right dialect in dataSource.groovy org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect

Comment: and why are you using postgresql jdbc for microsoft sql server?

Comment: This is not my project, so I just begin to explain it

I will look at the dialect in data source:

dialect="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect"

Comment: Compling error:

 Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: datetime2, at table: relationship, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(send_date)]

Could not determine type for: datetime2, at table: relationship, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(send_date)]

Comment: `    development {
        dataSource {
   
      pooled = false
      driverClassName = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
      
   dialect="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect"`

Comment: you are using postgresql-9.0-801.jdbc4.jar?